# Moment map of $\mathrm{O}(n)$-action on $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry, group-actions, symplectic-topology

Let $(\mathbb{C}^n, \omega_0)$ be the complex Euclidean space of dimension $n$ with the standard Kähler structure $\omega_0$. I am looking for a Hamiltonian $\mathrm{O}(n)$-action on $(\mathbb{C}^n, \omega_0)$ such that the preimage $\mu^{-1}(0)$ of $0 \in \mathrm{o}(n)^{*}$ under its moment map $\mu: \mathbb{C}^{n} \rightarrow \mathrm{o}(n)^{*}$ consists of the unique point $0 \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$.

I would appreciate any explanation or references where such an example is explained. Thank you.

Comment: I notice that you wrote "Hamiltonian" action and "its moment map" rather than "Poisson" and "the equivariant moment map".  (A Hamiltonian action has a moment map (which may not be unique), but it may not be $\mathrm{Ad}^*$-equivariant.)  Is there any significance to this?  Did you mean for us to assume that $\mu$ is $\mathrm{Ad}^*$-equivariant?  (In your particular situation, there always will exist such an equivariant moment map, and it will be unique.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Robert. Yes, I meant that $\mu$ is $\mathrm{Ad}^{*}$-equivariant. I can accept uniqueness of such a moment map. Then, what is a Hamiltonian $\mathrm{O}(n)$-action on $(\mathbb{C}^{n}, \omega_{0})$ except for the canonical  restriction of the linear $\mathrm{O}(n; \mathbb{C})$-action?

Comment: In that case, because you are assuming that $0 = \mu^{-1}(0)$, the action must fix $0$ (since $\mu^{-1}(0)$ must be a union of orbits).  Moreover, it must be an isolated fixed point.  The induced action on $T_0\mathbb{C}^n\simeq\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ must then be a representation of $\mathrm{O}(n)$ that fixes the symplectic structure on $T_0\mathbb{C}^n$ and that has no trivial summands.  By dimension count, it must be two copies of the standard represention of $\mathrm{O}(n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., the standard rep'n on $\mathbb{C}^n$.  But this rep'n doesn't work, so there is not one that does.

Comment: Thank you for verifying non-existence of the desired moment map. It is interesting to consider moment maps combined with representations of $\mathrm{O}(n)$. Do you know what book explains their relation?

Comment: I don't know a book that specifically addresses this sort of use of representation theory in symplectic geometry, but, since representation theory is a basic tool in geometry when symmetries are present, it's used often in symplectic problems.  Maybe a book that discusses the geometry of the moment map?

Comment: Thank you so much, Robert!